# Join-Table with metadata, composite key and one to many relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i am building a cart that can take items with specified versions.

I am using `Symfony 2.4.3` and `Doctrine 2`

I have following code for three entities, `Cart`, `CartItem` and `CartItemVersion`.

`Cart.php`

```
// ----

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart")
 */
private $cartItems;

// ----
```

`CartItem.php`

```
// ----

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart")
 */
private $cart;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
 */
private $item;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItemVersion", mappedBy="cartItem")
 */
private $cartItemVersions;

// ----
```

`CartItemVersion.php`

```
// ----

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CartItem")
 */
private $cartItem;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ItemVersion")
 */
private $itemVersion;

// ----
```

While updating schema, i got this error.

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
Column name `id` referenced for relation from CartItemVersion towards CartItem does not exist.
```

Then i gave name to the fields like `cartItem_id` in `CartItemVersion.php` and others.

Then updating schema returns,

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE cart_item_version ADD CONSTRAINT FK_4D3EA2E02EA80FC1 FOREIGN KEY (cartItem_id) REFERENCES cart_item (cartItemVersion_id)':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'symfony.#sql-3d8_12a' (errno: 150)
```

I have referred Doctrine 2's documentation and followed Use Cases for `OrderItem` but it seems that this is something because of composite primary keys, but still giving proper names couldn't solve this issue.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping you have a bunch of issues which are corrected as below. You need define the referenced Column name and its own column name; furthermore, for those field which has mappedBy you need to define inversedBy, too.

Cart.php

```
/**
* @var ArrayCollection
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart")
*/
private $cartItems;
```

CartItem.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", inversedBy="cartItems")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $cart;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $item;

/**
* @var ArrayCollection
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItemVersion", mappedBy="cartItem")
*/
private $cartItemVersions;
```

CartItemVersion.php

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CartItem", inversedBy="cartItemVersions")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $cartItem;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ItemVersion")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_version_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $itemVersion;
```

To get more info check [Relationship Mapping Metadata Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)

Comment: Before running update the schema after the above changes you need to make sure no index was created previously; if it was you need to drop those indexes manually

Comment: Still, same error. I did exactly you wrote, but same error saying column name I'd referenced for relation from CartItemVersion to CartItem doses not exist

Comment: @user3551525 Do you have `$id` in your `CartItem` and `ItemVersion` entities? Did you define them? They should be auto generated

Comment: No, there is a composite primary key as explained in doctrine's documentation. So this isn't possible without an auto incremental primary key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your entities slowly, step by step.
Begin with unidirectional and then add bidirectional when it is necessary...
By using [association mapping documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

This answer could be a comment but can't post a comment because of my reputation...